Assignment and copy of BigUint in generics
I would like to write code for unsigned integer (and later maybe signed integer) no matter their type. So the way to go is to use generic types and implementing the super trait "Unsigned". But I have a problem with BigUint.
Here is a basic code for an extended euclid algorithm.
use num::Unsigned;
use num_bigint::BigUint;

fn generic_extended_euclid<U>(a:U,b:U)->(U,U,U)
where
U: Unsigned + PartialOrd + Copy ,
{
    let one:U = U::one();
    let zero:U = U::zero();
    let two:U = one+one;
    let mut q:U;
    let ( mut r_temp, mut u_temp, mut v_temp):(U,U,U);
    let (mut u_1,mut v_1, mut u_2, mut v_2, mut r_1, mut r_2):(U,U,U,U,U,U)=(one,zero,zero,one,a,b);
    let mut n:U = zero;
    while !r_2.is_zero(){
        q=r_1/r_2;
        (r_temp,u_temp,v_temp) = (r_1,u_1,v_1);
        (r_1,u_1,v_1)=(r_2,u_2,v_2);
        if r_temp>=q*r_2{
            r_2=r_temp-q*r_2;    
        }else{
            r_2=q*r_2-r_temp;
        }
        (u_2,v_2,n)= (u_temp+q*u_2,v_temp+q*v_2,n + one);
    }
    if (n%two).is_one(){
        u_1=b-u_1;
    }else{
        v_1=a-v_1
    }
    return (r_1,u_1,v_1);
}


It works fine for any usual unsigned integer, but there is a problem with BigUint because it doesn't implement the Copy trait. So I can not assign using a mere = .
What is the solution for doing a generic code including BigUint ? Should I implement Copy for BigUint? Apparently it's impossible to implement Copy to an external struct.
I think I can do .clone() for each assignment and remove the copy binding, but is it normal practice?

Yes, clone() is normal. But there may be a way to save clones.

Also, == T::zero() and == T::one() is better written as .is_zero() and .is_one(), respectively.

@ChayimFriedman thanks for the tip. If I use clone, I guess I need to clone all values no matter the type.

@BenoitAvril: Sure, but aside from the overhead of typing out .clone(), it will run exactly as fast as if you hadn't typed it for all the Copy types.

@ShadowRanger ok fine then, ugly but fast, fine by me.
